# Two loader gifs handling two events in the same PHP page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a 'Loader' gif showed up in the same PHP page in two different instances.

1. One the page load
2. Other on form submission.

My script looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //on form submit
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
            $('#loaderImage').show();
            return true;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    // on page load
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".DivImage").fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

Corresponding `<div>` / `<img>` looks like this:

```
<div class="DivImage"><img src="loader.gif" style="height:30px; width:auto;" alt=""><br>Loading...</div>

<img src="loader.gif" alt="loader2" style="display:none; height:20px; width:auto;" id="loaderImage">
```

Unfortunately the `e.preventDefault();` does not seems to work in this instance where I see the page load 'Loader' also display on form submission.

Is there a workaround?

**EDIT**

With the comments I did edit the snippet like this however the issue remains unsolved.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //on form submit
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
            $('#loaderImage').show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    // on page load
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".DivImage").fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are returning true before you set preventDefault, so ***e.preventDefault()*** will never be called.

Comment: you may have to show the loader on the form submit event <form onsubmit="$('#loaderImage').show()"> and hide when it returns

Comment: @Esko I did remove the `e.preventDefault` and checked. Now the behavior I see is that the submit button on the PHP page doesn't work, hence the page validation doesn't take place

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing anything after **return**, it means that is not calling at all. In your case you are using **e.preventDefault()** after **return** so it is not calling.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj I did edit my question above. However the issue is that form validation stops since the `preventDefault` has prevented the php form validation on php button submit. Do you have a tip for me?

Comment: In your case can you try one thing, just wrap the #loaderImage img tag in a div, as you did for pageLoad img. And then manage the visibility according to wrapping divs. May be it helps you. Then i think you will not need to use  e.preventDefault()